# Slow SSH tunnel connection

Tags: ssh, tunnel

I have three machines:

1. mypc (Ubuntu 22.04, behind a NAT firewall)
2. myserver (Ubuntu 22.04, a server on the public internet)
3. openwrt (OpenWRT 23.05, on a NAS device behind a different NAT firewall)

I want to connect from mypc to openwrt using SSH. I cannot connect directly from "mypc" to "openwrt" due to neither device being directly reachable from the other (NAT).

I also cannot use port forwarding on the NAT routers, apparently due to the IPv6 NAT configuration which prevents a connection from outside to any NATed host.

So I have set up a reverse SSH tunnel using 'sshtunnel' from openwrt:22 to myserver:2222. I can now SSH into myserver:2222 to get a shell on OpenWRT.

**This works fine, but is super slow**; transferring data over this link never goes beyond 400kb/s although an upload from mypc to myserver runs at 4MB/s (not MBit/s!) and a download from myserver to openwrt does 5MB/s, and using `scp` or `rsync` directly *from* either end *to* myserver confirms this.

**Why is the tunnel connection so slow, and what can I do to speed it up?** I am aware that the tunnel is basically 'TCP-over-TCP' which adds overhead, but surely not a factor of 10? Adding compression does not help, the CPUs are far from being busy on either machine (only <20% of one core on the slowest machine of the three).

If SSH is the wrong tool to do this, what other options exist to accomplish a direct connection between two NAT-ed hosts with more bandwidth?

Comment: Aren't you trying to touch your nose by moving your arm around your head? Everything has to go through your "my server".

Comment: I can use another intermediate machine but I'm not sure if this solves the problem that I want to connect to the NATed 'openwrt' from 'mypc' somehow. 'myserver' has a GBit connection and sufficient CPU power to handle this, I'm pretty confident that it is not the bottleneck.

Comment: mypc and OpenWRT are  both behind a DSL router in private homes of different cities 800 kilometers apart. They both live within different private 192.168. networks and don't know of each other. Both ISPs are doing IPv6 with DS-Lite which as I understand prevents direct forwarded connections from the outside. Also I cannot access the router config that does the NAT on OpenWRTs side, I can only access OpenWRT